# decode html code from javascript to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, encoding, decoding

I have html application with jquery that send html code using jrequest via post method to php server-side, and then it(html code) will be decoded and saved as html file with php. at first time is everything works well until I found a special character (copyright/©) was decoded as � (wierd character). and then I try more special characters and the result is more stranger.

anybody had same experience like this?

detail:

function save(htmlString){

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    data: {html:htmlString, filename:getParameterByName('page')},
    success: function (data) {
        // this is executed when ajax call finished well
         alert('file has been saved');
         location.reload();
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // executed if something went wrong during call
        if (xhr.status > 0) alert("Error: " + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
    }
});
```

}

// saving html via ajax function to save.php

var t = $("html").html();

save(escape(t));

php code:

```
<?php

$htmlheader = '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
';

file_put_contents('test.html', $htmlheader.urldecode($_POST['html']).'</html>');

?>
```

I had tried others decoding function in php like html entities decoder etc. but.., the result is worse.. no luck :(

I used this tool : http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/ for finding the mehtod of encode/decode and it's useful .

***I got my answer .***

I just got my question, the solution is I add dataType option as "html" on jrequest and decode in php using url encode and then stripslashes.

decode in php

';





file_put_contents('test.html', $htmlheader.stripslashes(urldecode($_POST['html'])).'');


?>

**encode and send to php via jrequest**

function save(htmlString){

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
dataType:'html',// ***add this option!***
    data: {html:htmlString, filename:getParameterByName('page')},
    success: function (data) {
        // this is executed when ajax call finished well
         alert('file has been saved');
         location.reload();
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // executed if something went wrong during call
        if (xhr.status > 0) alert("Error: " + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
    }
});
}
```

var t = $("html").html();

save(t);// remove escape() function

I hope this helpful for anyone . Thanks :)